# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap3'

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I've installed `Anaconda` and python 3 on it. Next I've installed `django` and `django-bootstrap3`.

It's shown in pip freeze and it is in `C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` folder, but when I run my project this error appears:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap3'
```

why it doesn't know bootstrap 3?

Comment: What about `pip3`?

Comment: Did you add bootstrap3 in your INSTALLED_APP?

Comment: I also test with pip3, but no difference

Comment: and I add bootstrap3 in my INSTALLED_APP